# Capturing jpegs from an h264 stream with gstreamer on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi, openmax

I have one of the new camera add-ons for a Raspberry Pi.  It doesn't yet have video4linux support but comes with a small program that spits out a 1080p h264 stream.  I have verified this works and got it pushing the video to stdout with:

```
raspivid -n -t 1000000 -vf -b 2000000 -fps 25 -o -
```

I would like to process this stream such that I end up with a snapshot of the video taken once a second.

Since it's 1080p I will need to use the rpi's hardware support for H264 encoding.  I believe gstreamer is the only app to support this so solutions using ffmpeg or avconv won't work.  I've used the build script at http://www.trans-omni.co.uk/pi/GStreamer-1.0/build_gstreamer to make gstreamer and the plugin for hardware H264 encoding and it appears to work:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/streamtest# GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/gst gst-inspect-1.0 | grep 264
...
omx:  omxh264enc: OpenMAX H.264 Video Encoder
omx:  omxh264dec: OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder
```

So I need to construct a gst-launch pipeline that takes video on stdin and spits out a fresh jpeg once a second.  I know I can use gstreamer's 'multifilesink' sink to do this so have come up with the following short script to launch it:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/streamtest# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

export GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/gst

raspivid -n -t 1000000 -vf -b 2000000 -fps 25 -o - |  \
gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! decodebin ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/1 ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=img_%03d.jpeg
```

Trouble is it doesn't work: gstreamer just sits forever in the prerolling state and never spits out my precious jpegs.

```
root@raspberrypi:~/streamtest# ./test.sh
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
[waits forever]
```

In case it's helpful output with gstreamer's -v flag set is at http://pastebin.com/q4WySu4L

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing.  I haven't tried making gstreamer work yet, so I'll give it a shot and write back if I have any different results.

Comment: I've been talking to people on the gstreamer-devel list too.  Doesn't look hopeful: I'm hearing that raspivid's output lacks timestamps which gstreamer needs to make decisions about framerates.

See http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-jpegs-from-an-h264-stream-td4660254.html

Comment: Can the timestamps be added by modifying the raspivid source code?  Or does it have to happen at the GPU level?

Comment: That is beyond my ken.  Try asking jamesh on the rpi boards, I think he'll know.

Comment: That build script seems to be gone, has anyone mirrored it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally found a solution to this.  My gstreamer pipeline was mostly right but two problems combined to stop it working:

- raspivid doesn't add timestamps to the h264 frames it produces
- recent versions of gstreamer have a bug which stop it handling untimestamped frames

Run a 1.0 build of gstreamer (be sure to build from scratch & remove all traces of previous attempts) and the problem goes away.

See http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Capturing-jpegs-from-an-h264-stream-tt4660254.html for the mailing list thread.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your gstreamer binary for the Raspberry Pi that could be used for testing?

Comment: It's linked against a few other things so I doubt it would survive the journey.  But I've put the build script on pastebin; this should give you a working build similar to mine.  http://pastebin.com/u8T7mE18